# Rails API Versioning namespacing issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, serialization

I'm taking over a legacy rails project, and I'm having a problem getting the namespacing right for API versioning.

Following the lead of the previous developer, controllers and serializers are organized in versioned directories like so:

```
/controllers
    /api
        /v1
            ...api v1 controllers here
        /v2
            ...api v2 controllers here
/serializers
    /v1
        ...api v1 serializers here
    /v2
        ...api v2 serializers here
```

Then within the .rb files, it looks like the various components are accessed via namespaces that match that folder structure.  For instance:

```
class Api::V1::PostsController < ApplicationController

    def index
         @moves = Posts.all()
         render json: @moves, each_serializer ::V1::PostSerializer
```

And everything works great.  The problem is, if I want to access something from the V2 namespace from inside V1, I get an error.  For example, if I want to do something like this:

```
class Api::V1::PostsController < ApplicationController

    def comments
         @comments = Comments.where(:post_id => params[:id])
         render json: @comments, each_serializer ::V2::CommentSerializer
```

I get this error:

```
SyntaxError (
    /path/to/ptoject/app/controllers/api/v1/posts_controller.rb:22: syntax error,
    unexpected tLABEL
    render json: @comments, each_serializer: ::V2:CommentSerializer
                                               ^):
```

So what do I need to do to call into the V2 namespace from V1?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are trying to access a namespaced serializer.

You shouldn't be accessing the V2::CommentSerializer from V1 module.

Instead you should create a V1::CommentSerializer specifically designed for API::V1

Comment: Ok maybe the above is a bad example, because it's just a temporary measure I'm doing to get things working, but in my V2 controllers I'm can see myself wanting to call into the V1 namespace a lot rather than replicating all the functionality in V1.  Surely there must be a way to access the other version's namespace.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I think you are going wrong by versioning your APIs and calling the `V2` controller version inside the `V1` controller version, is a wrong way to think modularity. I solved ***my troubles*** using a different approach, using the inheritance concept also for `controllers`, like:

```
class Api::V1::ResourceController < ApplicationController
```

and after

```
class Api::V2::ResourceController < Api::V1::ResourceController
```

and the actions are like:

```
def custom_action
    #my custom code here, or use "self"
end
```

hope it helps you! I solved in this way and works perfectly!